# Is there a Keyword is in Java, similar to Python's "is"?

Tags: java, python, keyword

Is there anything like 'is' in Java? Something that would evaluate to true based on memory location?

```
a = 1
b = a
print(id(a))
print(id(b))

# if a is b condition will evaluate to true
# the above print statement gives the same memory ID. In my case: 14374435888

# above assignment b = a is not the same as below
a = 1
b = 1
```

Comment: In Java `==` is equivalent to `is`. You'd use `.equals()` in Java for Python's `==` operator.

Comment: depends on what you consider 'is'. Are we talking about 'the same object' or 'the same value'?

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for replying. Based on the same memory ID, I would say I am referring to the same object, at the same memory, with a different name.

Comment: @jpsamudrala then we're indeed talking about the == operator

Comment: You shouldn't think of `is` in terms of memory locations (and you shouldn't think of Java's `==` that way, either). `is` gives `True` if its arguments are the same object. Thinking of it in terms of memory is at the wrong abstraction layer, and introduces unnecessary confusion about what happens if objects get moved in memory or if new objects are allocated in the space used by an old object.

Comment: Thinking of `is` in terms of equal memory locations is like thinking of whether two humans are the same human by whether they're sitting in the same chair.

Comment: @Stultuske in python, `is` is the identity operator, `==` is an equality operator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, but seeing as we are talking about Java .. does that matter?

Comment: @Stultuske yes, the question *specifically* asks about `is` from Python, and the equivalent operator in Java, and you asked "what you consider 'is""

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and he answered that question, by stating comparison by memory address. (same memory, different name). is is indeed a Python operator, but it's also a verb.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out. Well answered. I guess from a use case standpoint, if I want something to evaluate to true based on given answer, I would use `==`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three strings:

```
String a = "first";
String b = "second";
String c = a;

// false, because they're in different memory locations
System.out.println(a == b);

// true, because they point to the same location in memory
System.out.println(a == c);
```

Comment: might it also be false because they're not the same String? Just wondering. replace that "second" with "first", and watch what happens then.

Comment: @Stultuske If I recall correctly, Java optimizers exploit the immutability of strings to allow two variables to reference the same string. There are some corner cases where the optimizer doesn't apply (i.e. you will get false if you do stringA == stringB when they have the same characters). You can't rely on the '==' operator to compare strings. Instead, you should use the String.equals method.

Comment: You recall incorrectly. If you use String b = "first"; a == b will return true, because the same of the pool is used. If you want to force a new one, you need to use String b = new String("first");

Comment: Thanks for the insight, what do you mean by "the pool"?

Comment: the String pool